# How can I use webpack to update the script tag in jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, pug

Is it possible to use webpack to simply update a jade/pug template's script tag to the minified/cache busted JS bundle? All of the examples I have found show how to use plugins to convert the jade template to HTML. I am serving the jade files with express and do not need them converted to html.

Any suggestions or sample configs would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. If anyone else runs into this, there is a plugin called html-webpack-pug-plugin available here: https://github.com/negibouze/html-webpack-pug-plugin.

By adding the code below to the plugins section the webpack config, the bundles will simply be added to the pug templates.

```js
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filetype: 'pug'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'output.pug'
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin()
]
```

Comment: for some reason output is still html